# Partial ordering of forwarding reference and normal reference with deduction guides

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

[gcc 8.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JmuyUxQCy7MvoNO7) and [clang 5.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZzSYuRgTDpErfGK7) disagree on the behavior of this program:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    A(const T&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    A(T&&)      { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

template <typename U> A(U&&) -> A<double>;

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    const int ci = 0;

    A a1(0);  // both say A<double>
    A a2(i);  // both say A<double>
    A a3(ci); // gcc says A<int>, clang says A<double>
}
```

gcc's behavior doesn't make sense to me - if the `const T&` overload is preferred to the `U&&` overload for lvalue `const int`, why isn't the `T&&` overload preferred to the `U&&` overload for rvalue `int`? clang's makes more sense to me (none of the functions is more specialized than the other, so deduction guide wins).

Who's right?

Comment: I'll take a stab at this. The deduction is for an rvalue (reference). `ci` is an lvalue of a `const`, and there happens to be a constructor that takes a reference to a `const` as a parameter.

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge, but how is this `->` syntax called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are in partial-ordering land again. The type of the synthesized function template parameters are

```
T&&      // #1: not a forwarding reference
const T& // #2
U&&      // #3: a forwarding reference
```

The pre-partial ordering transformation [strips away referenceness](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.partial#5) and after that the [top-level cv-qualification](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.partial#7), leaving us with a bare type in all three cases. It follows that in all three cases deduction succeeds in both directions. We are now left with [[temp.deduct.partial]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.partial#9)'s tiebreaker:

> If, for a given type, deduction succeeds in both directions (i.e., the
>   types are identical after the transformations above) and both P and A
>   were reference types (before being replaced with the type referred to
>   above):
>
> - if the type from the argument template was an lvalue
>     reference and the type from the parameter template was not, the
>     parameter type is not considered to be at least as specialized as the
>     argument type; otherwise,
> - if the type from the argument template
>     is more cv-qualified than the type from the parameter template (as
>     described above), the parameter type is not considered to be at least
>     as specialized as the argument type.

For `U&&` vs `T&&`, neither rule applies and there's no ordering. For `U&&` vs `const T&`, however, the parameter type `U&&` is not considered to be at least as specialized as the argument type `const T&`, per the first bullet.

Partial ordering therefore finds #2 to be more specialized than #3, but finds #1 and #3 to be indistinguishable. GCC is correct.

That said, this may well be an oversight in the partial ordering rules. Class template deduction is the first time we have a "rvalue reference to cv-unqualified template parameter that isn't a forwarding reference" thing. Previously, in double-reference cases, forwarding references will always lose to non-forwarding rvalue references at the second bullet (because the only way you get non-forwarding rvalue references is if you have `cv T&&` for some non-empty `cv`).

Comment: That all makes sense. Per the last paragraph, do you think the first bullet should cover non-forwarding rvalue reference too (i.e. preferring `T&&` to `U&&`)?

Comment: Iirc, overload resolution has tie breaker bullets that involves both partial ordering and checking whether one of two candidates was a deduction guide. It seems GCC and clang apply these tie breakers in different orders. I don't think it is about disagreement on partial ordering, but I am on android currently so I can't research.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You mean Clang doesn't implement [P0620](https://wg21.link/P0620)? Maybe. But the "why doesn't #1 beat #3 when #2 does" question is partial ordering.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That actually seems plausible. In [this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GXzAHJA5kRz7v2v9), clang picks `A<void>` (less specialized, user-declared deduction guide) and gcc picks `A<int>` (more specialized, constructor)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Filed [llvm bug 33295](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33295).